# Seekbar not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video, mp4, azure

I have uploaded a video to my Windows Storage and noticed, that the seekbar (of the default Chrome's html5 player) is not working. Url of that video is:

http://portalvhdsrwglplr5bdc2k.blob.core.windows.net/vdepot/uploads/video/file/167/surfer-girl-35094486.mp4

**Please note:** Seekbar is not working when video download is in progress or it's 100% the first time. If video has been downloaded by chrome player and you refresh the page, seekbar works fine.

I'm a video encoding newbie thus i'm not sure if that's the problem with the video, with browser or maybe with windows azure in some way? I also can't find anything about that topic in google.